# Remove parts of URL and redirect to specific page of site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a game site which recently migrated to wordpress, now I want to redirect the old URL to new one. Here's the example:

Old URL - https://www.website.com/fighting/stick-fighter.html
New URL - https://www.website.com/stick-fighter/

I fixed this by creating this in htaccess:

Redirect 301 /fighting/stick-fighter.html /stick-fighter/

But my games are 500+ with different category so I don't want to encode each every game in htaccess.
Is there a way to remove the category in URL which is "fighting" and remove the ".html" extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?<base>https?://www.website.com/)(?<catgory>fighting/)(?<page>.+?)(?<extension>\.html)$
```

Then combine "base" and "page" group

I am using C# like this:

```
string s1 = Regex.Replace(oldUrl, @"^(?<base>https?://www.website.com/)(?<catgory>fighting/)(?<page>.+?)(?<extension>\.html)$", @"$1$3/");
```

For the URL redirection, you should enable apache redirection by enabling "AllowOverride" in httpd.conf:

- Change AllowOverride from None to all

  ```
  Options FollowSymLinks 
  AllowOverride All
  ```
- Load redirect module

  ```
  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
  ```
- Change/Add rewrite rule

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(?<base>https?://www.website.com/)(?<catgory>fighting/)(?<page>.+?)(?<extension>\.html)$ $1$3/ [L]
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Comment: Hi, How do I put this inside the .htaccess? I'm using wordpress not asp.net c#

Comment: Update the answer.